# Android camera intent fails only in tablet

Tags: android, android-camera

this has been buging me for the past 2 days, 
only on tablet, tab2 10.1, when i launch the camera intent, after taking the picture and returning to the app, the Activity starts over, and the result on the onActivityResult gets me a blank image,
here are the implementations i did:

on the **manifest** i added the orientation because the the camera activity changes the orientation, so i fixed it with this

```
<activity
            android:name="com.test.babdar.Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/title"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
```

and on the activity

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

in the onActivityResult, the resultCode is always RESULT_OK;

and when i tracked down the behavious of the activity when it resumes, i got this:

1. onCreate
2. onActivityResult
3. onResume

so obviously the activity is destroyed, i dont know if this is a bug i dont know about or it's an usue with some workarround,

thank you all for your time

Comment: I had the same issue in Gingerbread, Samsung 7inch tablet. This was found only in the previous android versions. So just ignored the issue as we had to support the latest. The preview was blank, however when you save the image, its all good. You can try saving the raw bytes first and then showing the preview from the Image.

Comment: @prijupaul exactly that's what i ended up doing, saving the image in a file as i launch the camera activity,

Answer (score 1):

This is because of restarting the current activity due to low memory by OS. I faced the same issue in Galaxy S2 with 4.0.1. Ff you want to save something before restarting,you can use

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Comment: Nice catch! Even the sample app at http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html doesn't take this into account, so it wasn't working for me on a tablet.